# How to highlight or increase visibility of a single line in a pandas multiple line plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following df, weekly spend in a number of shops:

```
             shop1    shop2    shop3    shop4    shop5    shop6    shop7  \
date_week                                                                  
2          4328.85  5058.17  3028.68  2513.28  4204.10  1898.26  2209.75   
3          5472.00  5085.59  3874.51  1951.60  2984.71  1416.40  1199.42   
4          4665.53  4264.05  2781.70  2958.25  4593.46  2365.88  2079.73   
5          5769.36  3460.79  3072.47  1866.19  3803.12  2166.84  1716.71   
6          6267.00  4033.58  4053.70  2215.04  3991.31  2382.02  1974.92   
7          5436.83  4402.83  3225.98  1761.87  4202.22  2430.71  3091.33   
8          4850.43  4900.68  3176.00  3280.95  3483.53  4115.09  2594.01   
9          6782.88  3800.03  3865.65  2221.43  4116.28  2638.28  2321.55   
10         6248.18  4096.60  5186.52  3224.96  3614.24  2541.00  2708.36   
11         4505.18  2889.33  2937.74  2418.34  5565.57  1570.55  1371.54   
12         3115.26  1216.82  1759.49  2559.81  1403.61  1550.77   478.34   
13         4561.82   827.16  4661.51  3197.90  1515.63  1688.57   247.25   

             shop8    shop9  
date_week                    
2          3578.81  3134.39  
3          4625.10  2676.20  
4          3417.16  3870.00  
5          3980.78  3439.60  
6          3899.42  4192.41  
7          4190.60  3989.00  
8          4786.40  3484.51  
9          6433.02  3474.66  
10         4414.19  3809.20  
11         3590.10  3414.50  
12         4297.57  2094.00  
13         3963.27   871.25
```

If I plot these in a line plot or "spaghetti plot" It works fine.

The goal is the look at trend in weekly sales over the last three months in 9 stores.

I'd like to highlight some lines in this plot to make them stand out. For example, i can see `shop1` and `shop3` (blue and green) have increased towards the end. So I want them to be more visible.

```
newgraph.plot()
```

[image]

I am trying to replicate the method [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/123-highlight-a-line-in-line-plot/) to highlight lines on plots, but it's not working.

Apparently you can just re-plot the single lines you are interested in after plotting all lines.

```
df.plot()
plt.plot(df.index, df['shop1'], marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(df.index, df['shop3'], marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
```

But it doesn't change the plot like in the tutorial link. The plot is the exact same.

I've tried all sorts of line widths and alphas. I've also tried to extract the series first, then plot it:

```
df.plot()
extraline = df['shop1']
plt.plot(extraline.index, extraline.values, marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
```

But this doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

My df, if somebody want to test it out with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`:

```
{'shop1': {2: 4328.849999999999,
  3: 5472.0,
  4: 4665.530000000001,
  5: 5769.36,
  6: 6267.0,
  7: 5436.83,
  8: 4850.43,
  9: 6782.879999999999,
  10: 6248.18,
  11: 4505.18,
  12: 3115.26,
  13: 4561.82},
 'shop2': {2: 5058.169999999993,
  3: 5085.589999999996,
  4: 4264.049999999997,
  5: 3460.7899999999977,
  6: 4033.579999999998,
  7: 4402.829999999999,
  8: 4900.679999999997,
  9: 3800.0299999999997,
  10: 4096.5999999999985,
  11: 2889.3300000000004,
  12: 1216.8200000000002,
  13: 827.16},
 'shop3': {2: 3028.679999999997,
  3: 3874.5099999999984,
  4: 2781.6999999999994,
  5: 3072.4699999999984,
  6: 4053.6999999999966,
  7: 3225.9799999999987,
  8: 3175.9999999999973,
  9: 3865.6499999999974,
  10: 5186.519999999996,
  11: 2937.74,
  12: 1759.49,
  13: 4661.509999999998},
 'shop4': {2: 2513.2799999999997,
  3: 1951.6000000000001,
  4: 2958.25,
  5: 1866.1900000000003,
  6: 2215.04,
  7: 1761.8700000000001,
  8: 3280.9499999999994,
  9: 2221.43,
  10: 3224.9600000000005,
  11: 2418.3399999999997,
  12: 2559.8099999999995,
  13: 3197.9},
 'shop5': {2: 4204.0999999999985,
  3: 2984.71,
  4: 4593.459999999999,
  5: 3803.12,
  6: 3991.31,
  7: 4202.219999999999,
  8: 3483.529999999999,
  9: 4116.279999999999,
  10: 3614.24,
  11: 5565.569999999997,
  12: 1403.6100000000001,
  13: 1515.63},
 'shop6': {2: 1898.260000000001,
  3: 1416.4000000000005,
  4: 2365.8799999999997,
  5: 2166.84,
  6: 2382.019999999999,
  7: 2430.71,
  8: 4115.0899999999965,
  9: 2638.2800000000007,
  10: 2541.0,
  11: 1570.5500000000004,
  12: 1550.7700000000002,
  13: 1688.5700000000004},
 'shop7': {2: 2209.75,
  3: 1199.42,
  4: 2079.7300000000005,
  5: 1716.7100000000005,
  6: 1974.9200000000005,
  7: 3091.329999999999,
  8: 2594.0099999999993,
  9: 2321.5499999999997,
  10: 2708.3599999999983,
  11: 1371.5400000000004,
  12: 478.34,
  13: 247.25000000000003},
 'shop8': {2: 3578.8100000000004,
  3: 4625.1,
  4: 3417.1599999999994,
  5: 3980.7799999999997,
  6: 3899.4200000000005,
  7: 4190.600000000001,
  8: 4786.4,
  9: 6433.019999999998,
  10: 4414.1900000000005,
  11: 3590.1,
  12: 4297.57,
  13: 3963.27},
 'shop9': {2: 3134.3900000000003,
  3: 2676.2,
  4: 3870.0,
  5: 3439.6,
  6: 4192.41,
  7: 3989.0,
  8: 3484.51,
  9: 3474.66,
  10: 3809.2,
  11: 3414.5,
  12: 2094.0,
  13: 871.25}}
```

Comment: That's odd. Both of your code snippets are working just fine on my machine. Have you tried to run the example from the tutorial? And have you done anything else between `df.plot()` and the other plot-commands?

Comment: Hmm..  I have changed the column names so I could put my data on stack overflow. Perhaps I messed something up in my notebook while changing the dataframe.. I'll double check, thanks.

Comment: Yeah my stack overflow version works fine. Operator error, false alarm. Must find this bug.